# Issues when loading data with weka

Tags: weka

I am trying to load some csv data in weka. Some gene expression feature for 12 patients. There are around 22,000 features. However, when I load the csv file, it says

```
not recognized as an "CSV data files' file
```

to my csv file.

I am wondering is it because of the size of the features or something else. I have checked the csv file and it is nicely comma separated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would not encourage you to use CSV files in Weka. While it is entirely possible (http://weka.wikispaces.com/Can+I+use+CSV+files%3F) it leads to some severe drawbacks. Try to generate a ARFF file from your CSV instead.